# How to get value from disable dropdown in yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using active form in my view like

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ishead')
         ->dropDownList(
                array(
                  "1" => "I'm a Head",
                  "0" => "I'm not a head"
                 ), 
                ['prompt'=>'-Select a head type-']
           )
?>
```

By js, I have set the value and disable that dropdown

```
$("#register-ishead").val('1');
$("#register-ishead").prop("disabled", true);
```

When i submit the form, im not able to get that value of disable drop down value.

Is this procedure right? or How to do that

Answer (score 0):

First create a hidden field in the form.

After  the below code just assign the value to hidden field.
then only it will go after submit.

```
$("#register-ishead").val('1');
$("#register-ishead").prop("disabled", true);
```

Readonly does not work in dropdown.
You have to use disabled and keep the data in hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

One tricky way is to enable the dropdown just after submitting the form(before sending data to server). Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#YourFormID").submit(function(){
         $("#register-ishead").removeAttr("disabled");
         return true;
    });
});
```